# Google Maps result and Google Maps Api Result differs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
<script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        /*var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);*/
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=keygoeshere&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

I have checked for the following given address

> Source A: Orlando, Florida, USA
>
> Destination: Tampa RV, 4656 McIntosh Rd, Dover, FL 33527, USA

I have checked in both google maps and also using this API both have different results?
How to overcome this?

After so much of research I found a little bit weird behaviour.
When I calculate Lat, Lng using this I found different Lat,Lng for both

> My Code Lat and Lang Source : (-28.5383355 , -81.3792365) Destination
>   : (28.0213927, -82.2479693)
>
> While on google maps I saw top on the link bar I found this: Source :
>   (28.02142,-82.246769) Destination : (28.538537,-81.4095058)

While I am using this formula to calculate this:

```
  $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
$output= json_decode($geocode);
$pickup_at_latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$pickup_at_longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Any Solution

Comment: is this still happening?

Comment: yes still happening

Comment: I think it would be better to use the Google Maps API coordinates than the Google Maps because it doesn't give an accurate result.